# How to implement an authentication system in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have little experience with Next.js. I am making a website where I need the users to have a profile. But even after reading about how to implement authentication systems in Next.js, I still don't know how to do it.

Basically, I want the user to fill a basic form with an email, password, and some other info. Where should I start to work on the implementation of the authentication system?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have many options, here two of them:

1. Implement your own authentication system, Nextjs + Redux + API
2. Use one of those authentications methods from the third party like Google or Auth0 for example

To see an example of Auth0 you can check [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/next-js-authentication-tutorial/) and [this one too](https://auth0.com/blog/ultimate-guide-nextjs-authentication-auth0/)

To see an example using OAuth you can check [this article](https://medium.com/technest/next-js-oauth-with-nextauth-js-53a9f2b9994f)

This last example is from the [Vercel blog](https://vercel.com/blog/simple-auth-with-magic-link-and-nextjs)

Comment: Thanks! I checked Redux and it seems like a good option.